# Error at line 9/9: ORA-00902: invalid datatype ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_220200"

Tags: sql, oracle

> Error at line 9/9:
> ORA-00902: invalid datatype ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_220200", line 828 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658 ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_220200", line 813 ORA-06512: at "APEX_220200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2046

SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE BUILDING 
(
    BLDG_ID NUMERIC NOT NULL , 
    BLDG_DESC VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
);

ALTER TABLE BUILDING 
    ADD CONSTRAINT BUILDING_PK PRIMARY KEY (BLDG_ID);

CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT 
(
    DEPT_ID NUMERIC NOT NULL , 
    DEPT_DESC VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
);

ALTER TABLE DEPARTMENT 
    ADD CONSTRAINT DEPARTMENT_PK PRIMARY KEY (DEPT_ID);

CREATE TABLE DOC 
(
    DOC_ID NUMERIC NOT NULL , 
    DOC_LNAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
    DOC_FNAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
    BIRTHDAY DATE NOT NULL , 
    DEPT_ID NUMERIC NOT NULL , 
    DPOSITION VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
    SALARY MONEY 
);

ALTER TABLE DOC 
    ADD CONSTRAINT DOC_PK PRIMARY KEY (DOC_ID);

CREATE TABLE PATIENTS 
(
    PATIENT_ID NUMERIC NOT NULL , 
    PATIENT_LNAME VARCHAR(50) , 
    PATIENT_FNAME VARCHAR(50) , 
    BIRTHDAY DATE , 
    DOC_ID NUMERIC NOT NULL , 
    ROOM_ID NUMERIC NOT NULL , 
    BALANCE FLOAT 
);

ALTER TABLE PATIENTS 
    ADD CONSTRAINT PATIENTS_PK PRIMARY KEY (PATIENT_ID);

CREATE TABLE ROOM 
(
    ROOM_ID NUMERIC NOT NULL , 
    ROOM_DESC VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
    BLDG_ID NUMERIC NOT NULL 
);

ALTER TABLE ROOM 
    ADD CONSTRAINT ROOM_PK PRIMARY KEY (ROOM_ID);

CREATE TABLE STAFF 
(
    STAFF_ID NUMERIC NOT NULL , 
    STAFF_LNAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
    STAFF_FNAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
    BIRTHDAY DATE NOT NULL , 
    DEPT_ID NUMERIC NOT NULL , 
    SPOSITION VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
    SALARY MONEY NOT NULL 
);

ALTER TABLE STAFF 
    ADD CONSTRAINT STAFF_PK PRIMARY KEY (STAFF_ID);

ALTER TABLE DOC 
    ADD CONSTRAINT DEPT_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY (DEPT_ID) 
        REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (DEPT_ID) 
            ON DELETE NO ACTION 
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE PATIENTS 
    ADD CONSTRAINT PATIENTS_DOC_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY (DOC_ID) 
        REFERENCES DOC (DOC_ID) 
            ON DELETE NO ACTION 
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE PATIENTS 
    ADD CONSTRAINT PATIENTS_ROOM_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY (ROOM_ID) 
        REFERENCES ROOM (ROOM_ID) 
            ON DELETE NO ACTION 
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE ROOM 
    ADD CONSTRAINT ROOM_BUILDING_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY (BLDG_ID) 
        REFERENCES BUILDING (BLDG_ID) 
            ON DELETE NO ACTION 
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE STAFF 
    ADD CONSTRAINT STAFF_DEPARTMENT_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY (DEPT_ID) 
        REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (DEPT_ID) 
            ON DELETE NO ACTION 
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

to create table for staff

Comment: Hi - so which of those 17 (I think) statements is actually giving the error?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there are two errors in code you posted:

- there's no `MONEY` datatype in Oracle (use `NUMBER` instead)
- there's no `ON DELETE` nor `ON UPDATE` foreign key *action* (remove these clauses)

---

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE building (
  2      bldg_id   NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  3      bldg_desc VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  4  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE building ADD CONSTRAINT building_pk PRIMARY KEY ( bldg_id );

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE department (
  2      dept_id   NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  3      dept_desc VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  4  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE department ADD CONSTRAINT department_pk PRIMARY KEY ( dept_id );

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE doc (
  2      doc_id    NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  3      doc_lname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  4      doc_fname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  5      birthday  DATE NOT NULL,
  6      dept_id   NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  7      dposition VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  8      salary    NUMBER -- MONEY
  9  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE doc ADD CONSTRAINT doc_pk PRIMARY KEY ( doc_id );

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE patients (
  2      patient_id    NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  3      patient_lname VARCHAR(50),
  4      patient_fname VARCHAR(50),
  5      birthday      DATE,
  6      doc_id        NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  7      room_id       NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  8      balance       FLOAT
  9  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE patients ADD CONSTRAINT patients_pk PRIMARY KEY ( patient_id );

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE room (
  2      room_id   NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  3      room_desc VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  4      bldg_id   NUMERIC NOT NULL
  5  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE room ADD CONSTRAINT room_pk PRIMARY KEY ( room_id );

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE staff (
  2      staff_id    NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  3      staff_lname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  4      staff_fname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  5      birthday    DATE NOT NULL,
  6      dept_id     NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  7      sposition   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  8      salary      NUMBER NOT NULL --MONEY NOT NULL
  9  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE staff ADD CONSTRAINT staff_pk PRIMARY KEY ( staff_id );

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE doc
  2      ADD CONSTRAINT dept_fk FOREIGN KEY ( dept_id )
  3          REFERENCES department ( dept_id );

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE patients
  2      ADD CONSTRAINT patients_doc_fk FOREIGN KEY ( doc_id )
  3          REFERENCES doc ( doc_id );

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE patients
  2      ADD CONSTRAINT patients_room_fk FOREIGN KEY ( room_id )
  3          REFERENCES room ( room_id );

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE room
  2      ADD CONSTRAINT room_building_fk FOREIGN KEY ( bldg_id )
  3          REFERENCES building ( bldg_id );

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE staff
  2      ADD CONSTRAINT staff_department_fk FOREIGN KEY ( dept_id )
  3          REFERENCES department ( dept_id );

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Although not an error, Oracle suggests we use `VARCHAR2` instead of `VARCHAR` datatype.